# Use gtk3 in eclipse with c++

Tags: c++, eclipse, user-interface, project, gtk3

im learning c++ in combination with the gtk3 gui libary at the moment. But i don't know how to include it correctly. I am using eclipse with the cdt. After creating a project i can include it in the properties menu but if i do so i get the warning/error undefined reference on ... (in each line with a gtk3 function).
A can solve this error if i just use the pkg-config plugin but i can't create any c or c++ project if it is installed (NullPointerException).

Does anybody knows how to solve one of this problems?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `gnome-builder` which is tailored to the cration of Gtk+ applications in C/C++/Python.

If you want to set up eclipse with gtk that is indeed possible, but you need to take care of the include paths. I'd recommend to use the output of pkg-config and paste that into the linker fields of your project, same with includes.